# Importing another project in IntelliJ IDEA's buildpath/module?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, buildpath

I've been using Eclipse for awhile but I looking to possibly switch to IDEA. Eclipse has been a workhorse but its bugginess is driving me crazy.

My setup in Eclipse usually involves 2-3 projects being open, and one project being in the buildpath of the two other projects to serve as a library. How do I make this happen in Intellij? I think I'm supposed to create modules but it this is coming very counter-intuitively to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit different in IDEA.
Here's a link that'll help you understand:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea-vs-eclipse-terminology.html
Basically in IDEA project is a number of modules like workspace in eclipse.
So you need to add modules to your project and in the module settings(`<F4>`) add a module dependency.